# why dosen't the motor constraint work properly?

Tags: physics, constraints, rigidbody

I made a simple car with physics and rigid body constraints. The car can go downhill, but I wanted it to go uphill. so I added a motor constraint with an angular velocity of an inpulse of 10 and a max inpulse to the wheels. I connected the front wheels with the body using motor constraint but the motor constraint makes the body go forward, but the wheels keep rotating in the opposite direction of what it should be. I tried rotating the empty, but that just makes the body go backward and the wheels rotate forward. I have the body of the car selected for the first rigid body to be constrained in the motor parameters and the wheel on the second rigid body to constrained for every empty.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! I'd like to help, but I'm not sure what you mean by "motor constraint" because there isn't a constraint with that name as of Blender 2.92. Could you try adding a [minum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: he means the rigid body constraint - type motor